Confused about stack and file-based routing
In the index page I have three buttons: admin, trainer, user. When the user clicks admin there are a bunch of pages under admin same case for trainer. What's the stack order in this case?
Another issue is that under tabs if I have a button that navigates the user to another page where do I place the code for this page under (tabs), under admin?
Should I have a separate _layout.tsx for admin, trainer?
This is the file order:
app
   index.tsx
   admin
      (tabs)
      login.tsx
   trainer
      login.tsx

Here is the current _layout.tsx file in the root folder
<SharedContext>
      <Stack>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="index"
        <Stack.Screen
          name="admin/login"
          
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="admin/(tabs)"
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="trainer/login"
        />
      </Stack>
    </SharedContext>


In your current file structure and stack order for your React Native app, you have a root-level _layout.tsx file which handles the navigation between the different sections of your app (admin, trainer, user). Here’s a more detailed look at how to structure this:
Folder Structure
app
   index.tsx
   admin
      _layout.tsx
      (tabs)
      login.tsx
   trainer
      _layout.tsx
      login.tsx

_layout.tsx in the Root Folder
Your root _layout.tsx should manage the navigation to the different main sections (admin, trainer, user). Here’s an improved version:
<SharedContext>
  <Stack>
    <Stack.Screen name="index" component={IndexPage} />
    <Stack.Screen name="admin/login" component={AdminLogin} />
    <Stack.Screen name="admin" component={AdminLayout} />
    <Stack.Screen name="trainer/login" component={TrainerLogin} />
    <Stack.Screen name="trainer" component={TrainerLayout} />
    {/* Add user sections similarly */}
  </Stack>
</SharedContext>

Admin _layout.tsx
Within the admin folder, you can have another _layout.tsx that manages the admin-specific navigation:
<SharedContext>
  <Stack>
    <Stack.Screen name="admin/(tabs)" component={AdminTabs} />
    {/* Add other admin-specific screens here */}
  </Stack>
</SharedContext>

Trainer _layout.tsx
Similarly, within the trainer folder, you can have another _layout.tsx that manages the trainer-specific navigation:
<SharedContext>
  <Stack>
    {/* Add trainer-specific screens here */}
  </Stack>
</SharedContext>

Navigating with Tabs
If you have tabs under admin/(tabs) and need to navigate to another page, place the navigation logic within the appropriate component under admin/(tabs). You can handle navigation using React Navigation’s useNavigation hook or similar methods.
Example of a Tab Component with Navigation
Here’s an example of how a tab component might look:
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const AdminTab = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Admin Tab Content</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Another Page"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SomeOtherPage')}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default AdminTab;

File Order Recap
Here’s a recap of your updated file structure with the layout files:
app
   index.tsx
   _layout.tsx
   admin
      _layout.tsx
      (tabs)
      login.tsx
   trainer
      _layout.tsx
      login.tsx

By organizing your layouts this way, you keep the navigation logic modular and maintainable. Each section (admin, trainer, user) has its own layout and navigation logic, which is managed independently from the root navigation.

If I have a _layout file under admin, is it necessary to reference admin/login in the root _layout
